# How to remove old queued tasks in ThreadPoolExecutor and insert new tasks instead?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I load a lot of images form internet with a ThreadPoolExecutor.

When new images found, I need to render it first, in that case I want to abandon the old tasks which are still queued in the ThreadPoolExecutor and added these new items to download.

I found there are no "clear queue" method in ThreadPoolExecutor, and "purge" method sounds like not good for this.

What should I do?

I just thought to call "shutdown" of this executor and recreate a new one to do this, not sure whether it is appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried this?

```
ThreadPoolExecutor pool = .....;  pool.remove(task);
```

task is the Runnable you want to remove.

or if you want to clear the queue.

```
pool.getQueue().clear()
```

Comment: Although the javadoc says you really shouldn't use the getQueue method, that is probably the approach you want to go with based on the OP's question.

Comment: Yes, the javadoc says the getQueue method is not suggest to use, I just thought that is not a good way.

Answer (score 5):

`ThreadPoolExecutor` has a [`remove()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#remove%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method. You can use that in conjunction with `getQueue()` or keep your own collection of `Runnable`s that have been queue and might need removal. If you keep your own collection, remember to have some mechinism that removes the runnable from your collection when it has finished.